# Youtube API - Storing data for more than 30 days

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the YouTube Data API v3 to insert videos from my website to my youtube channel. It is all working fine. Youtube gives 10000 queries per day limit and I requested to extend the quota as one video upload takes about 1607 queries and hence my limit for uploading videos is 6.

The response I received from YouTube is that my API Client is in violation of Youtube's policy fo storing data. They have mentioned that

```
store_youtube_api_length: twelve months
```

and they want it to be set to under 30 days.

I have searched the google console for this setting but I'm unable to find it. I have asked Youtube and they have brushed off the request saying they are part of YT compliance team.

Can somebody here help me find it.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am getting the same notification from Google

Answer (score 4):

Responding to the YouTube API Services confirming our data retention policy was under the month limit fixed this for us. It was just an internal policy agreement, no setting to update.